# simple & fast sql server database backup and restore

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, backup, restore

I'm looking for a simple (simplest if possible) way of backing up and restoring a database.

I want to do a backup in one state and then after doing some operations get back to the backed up state.

Tried Database->Tasks->Back Up... and then Database->Tasks->Restore but I always get an error with:

`Restore failed for...DBName`

`The tail of the log for the database "database name" has not been backed up...`

So, I want to back up and restore with one simple operation each, can one advise me 
to a solution, be it GUI or not GUI based?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have Differential Backups set up. It is slightly more complicated than restoring a Full backup.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175510.aspx

By doing a Full backup, you are going to break the chain of backups that the DBA set up, so it would be a good idea to check first with the DBA before you break his backup set.

**Edited for very helpful comments:**

You should use the COPY_ONLY option when you do a backup so that you do not break the chain of backups.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx

Comment: He just needs to use COPY_ONLY Backups to avoid this issue http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1075

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`WITH REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191315.aspx) option of the RESTORE command:

> The REPLACE option overrides several
>   important safety checks that restore
>   normally performs. The overridden
>   checks are as follows:
>
> - Restoring over an existing database with a backup taken of another
>     database. With the REPLACE option,
>     restore allows you to overwrite an
>     existing database with whatever
>     database is in the backup set, even if
>     the specified database name differs
>     from the database name recorded in the
>     backup set. This can result in
>     accidentally overwriting a database by
>     a different database.
> - **Restoring over a database using the full or bulk-logged recovery model
>     where a tail-log backup has not been
>     taken and the STOPAT option is not
>     used**. With the REPLACE option, you
>     can lose committed work, because the
>     log written most recently has not been
>     backed up.
> - Overwriting existing files. For example, a mistake could allow
>     overwriting files of the wrong type,
>     such as .xls files, or that are being
>     used by another database that is not
>     online. Arbitrary data loss is
>     possible if existing files are
>     overwritten, although the restored
>     database is complete.

The topic is also covered at nauseam in MSDN see [Restoring Without Using a Tail-Log Backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179314.aspx), which contains the links for 'How  to' articles that cover Management Studio scenarios (ie. the tool you're using).

Answer (score 1):

When restoring you need to check the option to Overwrite existing database, if you are, otherwise it will fail.

MSSQL 2005 and up [features snapshots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx), sounds like it suits your requirements nicely.